# python3 mock member variable get multiple times

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

I have a use case where I need to mock a member variable but I want it to return a different value every time it is accessed.

Example;

```
def run_test():
    myClass = MyDumbClass()
    for i in range(2):
        print(myClass.response)

class MyDumbClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = None

 @pytest.mark.parametrize("responses", [[200,201]])
 @patch("blah.MyDumbClass")
 def test_stuff(mockMyDumbClass, responses)
     run_test()
     assert stuff
```

What I am hoping for here is in the run_test method the first iteration will print 200 then the next will print 201. Is this possible, been looking through unittest and pytest documentation but can't find anything about mocking a member variable in this fashion.
Just started learning pytest and unittest with python3 so forgive me if the style isn't the best.

Comment: Can you link me to the documentation I should be looking at for the change you suggested, been looking at unittest and still not quite understanding how doing a with statement with the patch would work for my use case.

Comment: Actually, disregard my above comment, it's pure garbage. I will write you an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap **myDumbClass.response** in a get function - say **get_response()** then you can use the **side_effect** parameter of the mock class.

- **side_effect** sets the return_value of the mocked method to an iterator returning a different value each time you call the mocked method.

For example you can do

```
def run_test():
    myClass = MyDumbClass()
    for i in range(2):
        print(myClass.get_response())

class MyDumbClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = None

    def get_response(self):
        return self.response

@pytest.mark.parametrize("responses", [([200,201])])
def test_stuff( responses):
    with mock.patch('blah.MyDumbClass.get_response', side_effect=responses):
        run_test()
    assert False
```

#### Result

```
----------------------------------- Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------------------
200
201
```

## Edit

- No need to patch via context manager e.g **with mock.patch**. You can patch via decorator in pretty much the same way. For example this works fine

  ```
  @patch('blah.MyDumbClass.get_response',side_effect=[200,100])
  def test_stuff(mockMyDumbClass):
      run_test()
      assert False
  ----------------------------------- Captured stdout call ------------------------------------------------------------
  200
  201
  ```

Comment: Is there no way to add a side_effect to a class member access call like .response?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do it. **side_effect** only appears to  work on  function calls